# Devil of a time with jQuery delegate and .not

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've searched hi and low but couldn't find a solution. I've tried everything.. but can't get this thing to work.

**NOTE: Can't use ".on()" . Using an older version of jQuery that only supports .live/.delegate**

basically, I have a very involved webpage.. and there are event handlers flying everwhere.. BUT, I basically want to attach a click event on the body BUT exclude certain id's. Great. Figured it would be easy.

tried:

```
 jQuery('body').delegate('.not("#mainID #anotherID")','click', function(e){ 
    // do something
 })

 jQuery('body').delegate(':not(".class1 .class2")','click', function(e){ 
    // do something
 })
```

etc...

and a bunch bunch more.. basically, cannot get this thing to work. No matter what I do, the whole page is clickable.

when I do something simple like: Great it works.

```
 jQuery('body').delegate('#someID','click', function(e){ 
    // do something
 })
```

But that isn't what i need. I need to basically allow for clicking on the whole body except for two subsets, smaller sections of the page. I figured this would be trivial.. but for some reason, just not working.

The two items I want to exclude are:
id: mainID w/ a class of ".class1"
id: anotherID w/ a class of ".class2"

another note: mainID sits outside of anotherID - two distinct sections of the page. Both divs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me point out few things related to event delegation:

1. First of all, use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function, `.delegate()` is deprecated.
2. Second, `.class1 .class2` will match `class2` which is inside of `class1`

   ```
   jQuery('body').on('click', ':not(.class1, .class2)', function(e) { 
       // do something
   })
   ```

But, **this is also not what you need**, you need:

```
$(".class1, .class2").on('click', function() { return false; });
```

If you are using older versions of jQuery and for some reason cannot change it, use `.live()` or normal `.click()` handler:

```
$(".class1, .class2").click(function() { return false; });
```

Now, if you click on `.class1` and `.class2` nothing will happen. If you want to select only specific `class` within a id you can use `#mainID .class1` as selector. Or with older event delegation:

```
jQuery('body').delegate(':not(.class1, .class2)','click', function(e){ 
    // do something
    // but this will execute on every where you click except .class1, .class2
})
```

Comment: Let me update my OP -- can't use .on -- using an older jQuery.

Comment: The rest of the answer should still apply though.

Comment: @starx, can you use "not" with a normal "click" handler like your last example? Because event though those two items are distinct(mainID, anotherID) - they reside within a bigger div.. so I have to address clicks on the "outer parent" and NOT mainID and anotherID. That is why I was trying to use '.not' and exclude those.